# Combining POST and GET in SpringMvc

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller, controller

For a user registration form (`registration.html`) I created a view controller through:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
      super.addViewControllers(registry);
      registry.addViewController("/user/registration").setViewName("registration");
  }
```

This works fine, and if I go to /user/registration (i.e. GET), I can see the registration form.

However if I now want to create a controller for POST requests at the same uri through:

```
@Controller
public class RegistrationController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public GenericResponse registerUserAccount(@Valid final UserDto accountDto, final HttpServletRequest request) {

         // some code
    }
}
```

I get an error message at the /user/registration uri saying:

> Request method 'GET' not supported

So it seems that my post controller is somehow overriding the GET controller which was working before. Why is that? Is it possible to make the two work together or do I have to write my own GET controller in the same way as my post controller?

Comment: addViewController you are getting registration view,if url is /user/registration,try to use different url on submit in view with post method, or call this url using ajax from client side using post http method.

Comment: Ok, all of your suggestions work. And it also works if in `class RegistrationController` I create a GET mapping `@RequestMapping(value = "/user/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)`. Still my question is, why the post controller in `class RegistrationController` is (seemingly) making the `addViewController` in `class MvcConfig` not work anymore?

Comment: check in browser the http type for /user/registration this url.it is making get http call to get template and same url is controller with post,there is no post http call for this url explicitly,so i think it is making call using get http method again.